# Eliminate redundancy between ktable internal topic and user topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm writing an app for a book library and I have 2 microservices: memberService, and bookService. The memberService creates a ktable of members (built by aggregating change messages on another topic) for its own internal use. The bookService also needs read access to that ktable. Currently I share the data by having the memberService call `memberTable.toStream().to("memberTableTopic")`
and I have the bookService subscribe to the memberTableTopic.

Based on my understanding of how ktables work, the data in memberTableTopic will be identical to the backing internal topic used by the ktable. Is there a good way to eliminate this redundancy? Should my bookService subscribe to the internal topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the data will look same in both topics- internal topic and usertopic.

Conceptully, Internal topics are used internally by the KStream Applications. That implies that when an application ID is reset, these internal topics will be deleted and you lose the data. While User topics exist externally to an application, that can be used by any application at any time.

That depends on your need how you want to use the data. If you want to remove the redundancy, you can set a short retention on your internal topics.

Comment: The internal topics for aggregates are supposed to have log compaction so I don't think I can shorten the retention time. After seeing how you're describing the internal concept, I guess it is ok to have 2 copies of the data, internal and public

Comment: We plan to add an optimization to use the output topic as changelog to avoid the redundancy: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6035 For now, it's up to you how much risk you are willing to take -- the safe bet is to accept the data redundancy.

Comment: Interesting, under the proposed optimization, what is to prevent another application from writing to the output topic? I assume that would mess with the ktable's ability to restore itself correctly.